Does the main clause function as head?


He could not catch the bus because he was late.


Is the clause 'he could not catch the bus' a head?
And is the other part 'because he was late' a dependent?
Normally if one part is dependent then the other part should be head, isn't it?
I mean main clause functions as head. Am I correct?


He could not catch the bus because he was late.

The part in italic
is the main clause or independent clause; we don't call it head.
The other part is the dependent clause.
The term head is used to refer to the  noun, verb, adjective, adverb, or preposition
in their respective types of  phrase.  For example, a noun phrase has a noun as its head; the rest of the phase are premodifiers or postmodifiers.
Cambridge Dictionary explains
head.
